# SQL - Can't get grouping query to work

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables (MS Access)

**tblInput**

```
Event, UserID, Score
EventA, 1, 50
EventA, 2, 55
EventB, 1, 45
EventB, 2, 33
```

**tblUser**

```
ID, Name
1     , John
2     , Alex
```

I need to show the winning score of each event, the event, and the name of the person. Output for this example should be

```
Event, Name, Score
EventA, Alex, 55
EventB, John, 45
```

I have tried this to get the event and top score:

```
SELECT Max(Score), Event FROM tblInput GROUP BY Event;
```

However, if I try to select the `ID` (Which I'm just using in the place of name, can change back to name when I join tables), I am forced to make it an aggregate function which I don't want to, or Place it in the Group by statement, which I get something like

```
SELECT Max(Score) AS Score, Event, ID FROM tblInput GROUP BY Event, ID;
```

```
Score, Event,  ID
165 EventA  2
173 EventA  9
170 EventA  32
211 EventB  10
224 EventB  14
256 EventC  16
188 EventC  17
```

Any help is appreciated, sorry for poor formatting.

Comment: An assignment actually, to build a database, not queries specifically, however I wish to add them, just haven't been able to come to a solution, have tried many times with no success. Thank you njk, that formatting helps a lot =)

Comment: Does each row in the event table T_Input have a unique ID? Because you need one.

Comment: Ah, forgot to mention that sorry, 'Event' is a primary key, and 'UserID' is also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one query like this:

```
SELECT 
 Max(Score) as topscore, 
 ChildEvent 
FROM 
 T_Participation 
GROUP BY ChildEvent
```

Then a second one built with the first query and your input table joined on both the event and score:

```
select
 childEvent,
 topscore,
 StudentID
from
 query1 q inner join
 t_participation p on
 q.childevent = p.childevent and
 q.topscore = p.score
```

what if you have more than one user with the top score?
Like for event A, user 3 has a score of 55?

Comment: Alright, I tried that, and it works. I didn't know you could alias stuff by 'query1 q' either, that's helpful. I had to alias the inner query because of ambiguity in which table it was trying to read. As for you question, both records will appear. I had tried something like this before, but without the last inner join. That is really help thanks, and helps me to understand better, which is more important to me than grades. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can do it in one statement. You need to create a table of events and their max score. Then join that table back to your Input table. Your example has your table name as T_Input, but your implementation uses T_Participation. Please substitute T_Participation for T_Input that is the correct table name.

```
SELECT T.EVENT, T.Score,  U.Name 
FROM T_Input T
    INNER JOIN T_User U ON T.UserID = U.UserID
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT Event, MAX(Score) [Score]  
    FROM T_Input T2
        INNER JOIN T_User U2 ON T2.UserID = U2.UserID
    GROUP BY EVENT
)Top_scores ON T.EVENT = Top_scores.EVENT AND T.Score = Top_Scores.Score
```

Comment: Thanks Rodney, it's good to see variation in how to get to a solution, will definitely play around with both samples tomorrow and get a better feel of SQL. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
SELECT T_Input.Event, T_User.Name, T_Input.Score
FROM
    (SELECT Max(Score), Event FROM T_Input GROUP BY Event) AS maxScores,
    T_User,
    T_Input
WHERE maxScores.score = T_Input.score
    AND maxScores.Event = T_Input.event
    AND T_User = T_Input.UserId
```

Comment: I'm not sure on line 3 here, it doesn't make sense to me that a table? and columns are in the the FROM statement?

Comment: @Deley Its a subquery, you can use the results of a query as if it were a table. That way you can restrict the data on a table and then join that with other tables (or sub queries) for the result your looking for.